# proof with induction $2^n + 4 > n^2 + 2n$

Tags: induction

prove w/ full induction : $2^n + 4 > n^2 + 2n$.
Let's skip the other steps for a moment, I'm just getting stuck with the proof
the claim is: $2^{n+1} + 4 > (n+1)^2 + 2(n+1)$
and now the proof  $$2^{n+1} + 4 > 2 * 2^n + 4$$ $$> 2 * (n^2 + 2n)$$ $$> 2n^2 + 4n$$
i am stuck here

Comment: Please learn to use Mathjax which makes reading easy.

Comment: I've noted that in two of your previous questions, people have linked you to the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please do try to familiarise yourself with it. To format this question (an easy one), basically just add `$` signs around your mathematical symbols. For example, `$2^n + 4 > n^2 + 2n$` becomes $2^n + 4 > n^2 + 2n$. Please do experiment with it, as people will become less and less willing to format your questions for you.

Comment: thank u guys, i'm trying to use mathjax :)

Comment: but can somebody help me with the actual task ... please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that for $n\geq5$

$$2^n+4>n^2+2n$$

Assume that for $n=k$
$$2^k+4>k^2+2k$$

Let's show for $n=k+1$

$$2^{k+1}+4>(k+1)^2+2(k+1)$$

Now

$$2(2^k+4)>2(k^2+2k)$$

$$2^{k+1}+4>2k^2+2k-4$$

$$2^{k+1}+4>2k^2+2k-4>(k+1)^2+2(k+1)$$

$$2k^2+2k-4>k^2+4k+3$$

$$k^2-2k-7>0$$

for $k\geq5$

$$(k-1)^2-8>0$$

Comment: where did u get the -4 on the right side?

Comment: @mathslooser   :   $2(2^k+4)>2(k^2+2k)$, $2^{k+1}+8>2k^2+2k$, $2^{k+1}+4>2k^2+2k-4$

Answer (score 1):

Please note this is not true for low values of $n \in \mathbb{Z+}$ up to $4$.

Just your induction step -

If $2^{n} + 4 > n^2 + 2n$ is true

we need to prove $\, 2^{n+1} + 4 > (n + 1)^2 + 2(n+1)$

$2^{n+1} + 4 = 2 \times 2^{n} + 8 - 4 = 2 (2^{n} + 4) - 4$

$ \gt 2n^2 + 4n - 4 = n^2 + (n+1)^2 + 2(n+1) - 7 = (n+1)^2 + 2(n+1) + (n^2 - 7)$

As $(n^2 - 7) \gt 0$ for $n \geq 3$, this is true.

Answer (score 0):

The claim is $2^{n+1} + 4 > (n+1)^2 + 2(n+1)$

Assuming it is true for $n$, that is $2^n + 4 > n^2 + 2n\to 2^n>n^2+2n-4$ we have
$$2^{n+1} + 4=2\cdot 2^n+4>2\left(n^2+2n-4\right)+4=2n^2+4n-4=(n^2+2n+1)+(2n+2)+n^2-6$$
$$>(n+1)^2+2(n+1);\;n>2$$
Proved